# After Generating pdf using Itext Sharp on a button click, Another button click on the same page,won't trigger

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, itext

I am using Itext Sharp to create pdf's for a existing order on my site on a button click. It has been added as a web part on Sharepoint site.

On the Same Page , there is another web part with many server controls. But, when I click on any of the buttons , button click event is not triggerning. Only when I refresh the page, the event is getting triggered.

I am not able to simultaneously create a pdf and then immediately click on another button without page refresh. I dont understand what am I doing wrong.

Below is my code.

```
  protected void PdfGenerate_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Font Arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, BaseColor.BLACK);
      string imagename = "AAlogo.gif";
      string imagepath = Page.Server.MapPath("/_layouts/Images/ImagesFolder/Image1.gif" ) ;

      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
          using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,15,15))
          {
              PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms); 
              document.Open();
              Paragraph img = new Paragraph();
              Image aaImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
              img.Add(aaImg);
              img.IndentationRight = 5f;
              //code to add all the elements here  
              PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
              PdfPCell col1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("oRDER Number"));
              table.AddCell(col1);
              //  code for the table...
                  document.Add(table);
              }
             document.Close();
          }
          Response.Clear();
          Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
          Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= Order Number" + .pdf");
          Response.Buffer = true; 
          Response.Clear();
          var bytes = ms.ToArray();
          Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
          Response.OutputStream.Flush();
      } 

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you Clear and Flush the Response, you are interrupting/aborting asp.net's page life cycle. It's better to put that download section in another file (Page_Load of the separate file) and call it from the current page. more info: [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820161/forcing-a-postback-asp-net) and [+](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/no-postback-after-downloading-file-in-aspnet-web-application.aspx)